# Concatenating values in mysql where multiple rows in one table relate to one row in another table without displaying several rows

Tags: mysql, database

I've have gone through stackoverflow for days and googled a lot but can still find the solution.
I have 2 tables profile and qualification
in the table profile

```
  pro_id  surname    firstname   
--------  --------  ------------

   1  John James           
   2  King Fred        
   3  Paul Smith      
   4  Cindy Hayes

Qua_id  Degree   School   Year
------  ------   ------   -----
   1  MBA  Wharton university 2002          
   1  LLB  Yale University 2001    
   2  BSc  Covington University 1998
   2  BEd  Kellog University 1995
   2  Msc  MIT 2011
   3  MBA  Havard Business School 2002          
   3  MSc  Yale University 2012     
   4  BSc  University of Edinburgh 2010
   4  BA   University of Liverpool 2009
```

Now what i want to achieve is this

```
1  John James MBA  Wharton university 2002,  LLB  Yale University 2001
2  King Fred  BSc  Covington University 1998, BEd  Kellog University 1995, Msc  MIT 2011
3  Paul Smith MBA  Havard Business School 2002, MSc  Yale University 2012  
4  Cindy Hayes BSc  University of Edinburgh 2010, BA   University of Liverpool 2009
```

But what i currently have is :

```
1  John James MBA  Wharton university 2002  
1  John James LLB  Yale University 2001 
2  King Fred  BSc  Covington University 1998 BEd  
2  King Fred Kellog University 1995
2  King Fred Msc  MIT 2011
3  Paul Smith MBA  Havard Business School 2002
3  Paul Smith MSc  Yale University 2012  
4  Cindy Hayes BSc  University of Edinburgh 2010
4  Cindy Hayes BA   University of Liverpool 2009
```

Here is my code

```
 Select pro_id, surname, firstname concat(degree,school,year) as qual from profile,qualification Where profile.proid=qualification.qua_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select pro_id, surname, firstname, group_concat(degree,school,year) as qual
from profile
left join qualification
on qualification.qua_id = profile.pro_id
group by qua_id
```

your filed names look a little odd - qua_id should perhaps be profile_id (which I think shoudl really be user_id - ie they should both be a user id and foreign keys to a user table).

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(degree,school,year) )`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! Your comment on the field name is noted

Comment: what if i am adding a third table and i intend to concat the values too